# How can I use template blocks in django?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I'm trying to load a header template into my index with {% block %} but I can't get it to load

**index.html**

```
<body>

    <header>
        {% block header %}{% endblock %}
    </header>
<h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
```

**header.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block header %}
<div class="header">
    <a href="/category/"><i class="fas fa-archive"></i></a>
    <a href="../"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
    <h1>hey</h1>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'category/index.html', context)
```

The app is installed in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get things to work the way you wanted you would need to make header.html the base template then extend index.html off of it.  This is because header.html is only substituting in {% block header %} when you render header.html.  Index.html doesn't see any of these substitutions when rendered.  You may want to make the header.html file a static file and load it in that way. Similar to how you would with css.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want to you should render header.html now, check django docs.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have a layout and then put the header block inside it.

**layout.html**

```
...
<body>

    <header>
        {% block header %}{% endblock %}
    </header>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
   <footer>
        {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
    </footer>


</body>
...
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block header %}
   the header
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
   here the content
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
   here the footer
{% endblock %}
```

Now you can render the index.html in your view